# AutoCompleteTextView - disable filtering

Tags: java, android, filter, android-arrayadapter, autocompletetextview

I'm retrieving a list of strings from a `webservice` and I want to list them up on a `AutoCompleteTextField` regardless of the built-in `AutoCompleteTextField` filters.

How do I do that? is there a way to disable it's inner filtering easily (preferably without subclassing)
I've loaded all my results into a `ArrayAdapter`, the problem is that some of them don't show up because of the filtering.

If I'm going in the wrong direction please point me to the right direction.

Comment: Lost half my day. Thank you brother :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I subclassed `ArrayAdapter`, Disabled the filters by Overriding it's `getFilter` method, and Made my `HTTPRequest` during the "text changed" events.

Comment: hi thanks Alon i hav same prob . i would be grateful to you if you can post some related code. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add some code or describe your solution.
i am totally stuck on this.

Comment: @Rajivyadav did the new answer by Krzysztow help you?

Comment: I got all of this to work the same way. Sub-classed ArrayAdapter; overrode getFilter() returning null as you did in performFiltering(). I am also getting my dropdown data from a web api call in onTextChanged(); calling an AsyncTask to retrieve the data and in onPostExecute() set the adapter list and notifyDataSetChanged(). I override getView() in my ArrayAdapter in order to set the dropdown layout items. I have to wonder whether AutoCompleteTextView is the right solution here, but I don't have a better one. And, I haven't yet figured out how to set the Text on item selection.

Comment: Ah! AutoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(...) to call setText() when item is selected from dropdown where the dropdown list is a data class.

Answer (score 43):

Probably @Alon meant subclassing `ArrayAdapter`, instead of `AutoCompleteTextView`. In `getFilter()` method one has to return a custom filter, that performs no filtering at all (in its `performFiltering()`). Probably the performance could be a problem - because theread is spawned. The best thing would be to derive from TextEdit and implement own completion popup. But this is again too many hassle for me, so far. Finally, I did something as follows and it works for me. Any feedback appreciated.

```
public class KArrayAdapter<T> 
extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    private Filter filter = new KNoFilter();
    public List<T> items;

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public KArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<T> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        Log.v("Krzys", "Adapter created " + filter);
        items = objects;
    }

    private class KNoFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence arg0) {
            FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                result.values = items;
                result.count = items.size(); 
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence arg0, FilterResults arg1) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 21):

When setting text to the AutoCompleteTextView, use `setText(CharSequence text, boolean filter)`.
Set filter to false, this sets the text without activating the filter

Comment: This is the much needed answer!

Comment: This should be the selected answer. It works flawlessly without needing to write extra code or overriding adapters.

Answer (score 9):

I solved my problem by making a custom adapter extending `ArrayAdapter` class and overriding its `getFilter()` method. By doing this the list will not be filtered based on any text placed in the TextField and all items will be displayed.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull Object[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull Object[] objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    public MyAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this while looking for a similar thing, but in what could be a bit unusual setup - using `AutocompleteTextView` as a Spinner (it's useful when you want a spinner wrapped in `TextInputLayout`).
I'm also using `app:simpleItems` approach for providing items instead of a custom adapter like so:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                                android:id="@+id/sizes"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:inputType="none"
                                app:simpleItems="@array/sizes" />
```

There are two approaches that worked and don't require you to subclass the adapter:

1. Call `setText(text, false)` in your `onItemClickListener`

```
view.findViewById<MaterialAutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.sizes).onItemClickListener =
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
            setText(adapter.getItem(position).toString(), false);
        }
```

2. Set empty array to filters.

```
view.findViewById<MaterialAutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.sampler).filters = arrayOf()
```

Hope this helps someone.