# AutoCompleteTextView (setText) and fragment.detach().attach()

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, autocompletetextview

I make app and add this function change language. I change language in fragment from MainActivity used

```
...
        val locale = Locale("es")
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val configuration = Configuration()
        configuration.locale = locale
        this.resources.updateConfiguration(configuration, null)
...
 supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().
           detach(scaleFragment).attach(scaleFragment).commit
...
```

in fragment CreateView

```
    ...
    val listSpeed = Scales.initSpeedsList().map{String.format("%.1f", it)}
  
    val adapterSpeed: ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(
            requireContext(),
            R.layout.list_item_scale,
            listSpeed)
    
    bindingScale.editSpeed.setAdapter(adapterSpeed)
    bindingScale.editSpeed.setText(bindingScale.editSpeed.adapter.getItem(1).toString(), false)//1
    ...
```

if I comment out line 1 (setText), then the field is empty and the dropdown list consists of 5 lines (5 lines should be). if line 1 is uncommented, then the field is filled and the drop-down list is one line or nothing at all. if I don’t do supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(scaleFragment).attach(scaleFragment).commit(i.e. I don’t translate the page into another language) then everything works correctly - the field is filled in and the drop-down list contains all the necessary options

```
     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/editSpeedLayout"
  

style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense.ExposedDropdownMenu"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:hint="@string/speed_head"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/editVoltageLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/textHeaderScale"
            app:suffixText="@string/mm_per_sec">
    
            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editSpeed"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="none" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

what am I doing wrong. Sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

I am not accounting for what AutoCompleteTextView filters the list according to the entered value. it is necessary to disconnect the filter in the adapter. If the filter is not disabled, then when the fragment is redrawn, it will display in the adapter only those results that will satisfy the filtering conditions. [AutoCompleteTextView - disable filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512762/autocompletetextview-disable-filtering)